# How to execute particular search query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have the following index `mytestindex` and type `mytesttype` in Elasticsearch 5.5:

```
PUT /mytestindex
{
    "mappings": {
      "mytesttype": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true
      },
        "properties": {
          "Id": {
            "type":"text"
          },
          "RadarId": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "VehicleId": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "Datetime": {
            "type":"date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          },
          "Hour": {
            "type":"integer"
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I am a very beginner in Elasticsearch. I would like to know if it is possible to get the hourly average number vehicles between 11:00 and 12:00? Which type of query should I use? For example, in MySQL I would do something like this (simplified version without considering 11:00-12:00):

```
SELECT    AVG( value ), datetime
FROM      mytable
GROUP BY  HOUR( datetime )
```

Is it possible to execute a similar query in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand from the question if you are interested in the number of elements per hour or the average of their values?
If you want the number of elements, you can use [Date Range Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html)

example:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
            "ranges": [
                { "to": "now-1H/H" }, 
                { "from": "now-1H/H" } 
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```